# How to set up flutter android emulator in VS code

Tags: dart, flutter, visual-studio-code

In the latest `flutter 0.5.1` release version they say you can launch an `emulator` in `browser`. Does anyone know how to get this up and working??

Comment: Where did you find that release note?

Comment: [Here. Tooling for Flutter Release Preview 1](https://medium.com/flutter-io/flutter-release-preview-1-943a9b6ee65a?linkId=53249457)

Comment: I actually read that article wrong. Sorry

Comment: @KevinRobert Then, please delete the question. This helps pushing other question that might need some attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to launch an emulator in the browser; I think there is a screenshot that's badly-placed in that article that might have confused things. The screenshot is unrelated to launching emulators.

However, launch real emulators (not in the browser) is indeed supported in VS Code. As long as you have >= v0.5.1 of Flutter and v2.13 of the Dart plugin for VS Code, you can indeed launch emulators from the editor.

Taken from the [release notes](https://dartcode.org/releases/v2-13/#emulator-launching):

### Emulator Launching

Emulators can now be launched directly from within Code. If you start debugging without a connected device you'll be presented with a list of emulators on your system to launch.

[image]

After selecting a device a notification will appear while the device boots and connects.

You can also trigger the emulator selection by clicking on `No devices` in the status bar or by running the `Flutter: Launch Emulator` command from the command palette.

[image]